# MAXIM31855T thermocouple chip, is there a through hole equivalent that works on the spi bus, having problems with SMD routing

Tags: temperature

I need to produce a circuit board to measure 16 temperatures from different thermocouples of  types J and T, Maxim has the perfect chip, the MAX31855(T,J), the only problem is that it is surface mount and my CNC PCB router which is a Chinese 3020 hack does not like the tight tolerances required for SMD.

I was wondering if there is an equivalent through hole chip that operates on the SPI bus? I want to use an Arduino DUE and a multiplexer chip (CD74HC4067E1) to read the individual temperature chips via the chip select pins and the SPI bus. 
Does anyone have any thoughts on this?

Comment: Adafruit and I think also sparkfun sells breakout boards for those chips, otherwise, why not use a PCB fab for this particular job?

Comment: I guess you meant MAX3185**5**, because MAX3185 exist, but it is a RS232 level translator. Well, I'd suggest the same thing as whatsisname. This is a very specialized chip, you won't find equivalents easily (even in SMD), and since DIP is mostly obsolete now, there is *very* little chance it exists.

Comment: You can get 5x5cm PCBs (doublesided, 10 boards/order) for $1.40 from various Chinese fabs. Probably best to get your own boards built. Limiting yourself to THT parts is no fun; trust me, I've been there, done that.